# How to compile a webapp to an hybrid one/jpk for my mobile phone without framework?

Tags: html, mobile-application

I have to build a hybride app, out of my webapp. It´s not allowed to use a middleware framework like phonegap which just builds it. In my app I want to show that HTML5 already allows to use a lot of functions of the mobile phone like the geolocation, instead of frameworks which can do the same, so I cannot use the framework for building my app. Which program should I use, VS? And how can I build my application(jpk) without a framework like that to test it on my mobile phone?

Comment: I believe that for Stackoverflow this question is both too broad and too opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple application with a webview and run your webapp inside this webview.

The problem is: hybrid frameworks like Cordova or Phonegap arent supose to just implement mobile features like camera or gps, they are useful writing once and run everywhere without complaining about iOs and Android code or even for fallbacks. Probably in the future youre not even going to install applications in your phone to use all mobile features using only browser features.

Here are some helpful links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive

Comment: ok, i will have a look. But is it possible to build an apk out of my webapp just with html5 and without using a framework?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to build an APK out of your webapp without using a hybrid mobile framework.